# Change input password from varchar to md5 in Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter

Can you help me ? i want change password type from varchar to md5

code:

```
$data = array(
              'email' => $this->input->post('email') ,
              'password' => $this->input->post('password')
                      );
```

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function such as MD5 or better is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of md5 use password hashing. php has built in function.

```
password_hash(string,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

to verify it.

use password verify method.

```
passord_verify($password,$hashed_password);
```

In your case you can do

```
$data = array(
              'email' => $this->input->post('email') ,
              'password' => password_hash($this->input->post('password'),PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
                      );
```

Make sure database column has appropriate char length. if its string type then its not problem.